# which is the best javascript library for making canvas compatible with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, canvas

I have an application with heavy use of canvas (dinamyc created, circles, squares, a brush pen, some kind of online microsoft paint). I am searching for the best compatible canvas js library for supporting IE7+.
Any suggestions? i tried excanvas.js but I didn't get the same results as i use to see in firefox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There [ExCanvas](https://github.com/arv/explorercanvas) (VML), [Uupaa Canvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20160408114243/https://code.google.com/p/uupaa-js-spinoff/) (VML, based on ExCanvas), [FxCanvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20210919233024/https://code.google.com/archive/p/fxcanvas) (Flash) and [FlashCanvas](https://web.archive.org/web/20220419155414/https://code.google.com/archive/p/flashcanvas) (Flash). There is also [this one](https://web.archive.org/web/20150728085253/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/08/24/using-one-platform-to-build-another-html-5-s-canvas-tag-implemented-using-silverlight.aspx) (Silverlight), but I don't know if this was totally finished. Note that ExCanvas also supports Silverlight in a sub-project, but it is not maintained.

It all depends on your target audience and what you need in your app.

The VML based ones are limited if you need lots of elements in your drawing, and the Flash based ones won't be limited by the number of element, but by the interactivity (mouse and keyboard events).

I suggest you to look at the respective websites of these libs.

Comment: The problem is that none of them support todataurl() method, and i really need it.

Comment: Yes, FxCanvas and FlashCanvas both support toDataUrl. FxCanvas supports it in a different way, because it needs a callback function, but FlashCanvas seems to work the same way as native implementation (with JPEG and PNG)

Answer (score 0):

The only think I can think of is [ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)